# JS - Detect Touch device didnt work API 3

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, google-maps-api-3

I try to detect if the user device is a touch screen but when i do with `'ontouchstart' in window` condition dont work well.

I try to desable the dragg only for touch screen device *(I hope this is the better solution for a full width gmap in mobile for avoid the scroll bug in touch)*

Can you help me to find the problem ? I've checked a lot of Starkoverflow subject but in dont find the good solution i'm blind maybe.

```
 function initMap() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    if ('ontouchstart' in window){
    var isDraggable = !("ontouchend" in document);
    }
    else {
    var isDraggable = !('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement);
    }
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        styles: WHITE,
        draggable: isDraggable,
        scrollwheel: false,
    };
```

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#ui-events).

Each Maps JavaScript API object exports a number of named events. Programs interested in certain events will register JavaScript event listeners for those events and execute code when those events are received by calling addListener() to register event handlers on the object.

Adds the given [listener function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapsEventListener) to the given event name for the given object instance. Returns an identifier for this listener that can be used with *removeListener().*

```
var isTouch = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
if(isTouch)
console.log("Touched");
else 
console.log("Can't touch this");
});
```